# Eclipselink lazy loading issue for objects with discriminator column

Tags: java, jpa, join, eclipselink, discriminator

We have following hierarchy in  our application:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractDemandOrMeasureBE {
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name = "V_VIEW2")
public abstract class AbstractDemandOrConcreteMeasureBE extends AbstractDemandOrMeasureBE {
    @Column(name = "VC_ID")
    private Long vcId;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class MinimalDemandBE extends AbstractDemandOrConcreteMeasureBE {
   ..
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@HasRelationsAnnotatedAsLazyLoaded
public class ValidationMeasureBE extends AbstractDemandOrConcreteMeasureBE {
..
}
```

In other object I am trying to load those entities like that:

```
@Table(name = "V_VIEW2")
public class VCBE extends SomeVeryAbstractBE {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VC_ID")
    private List<ValidationMeasureBE> validationMeasures;
    public transient static final String ATTRIBUTE_VALIDATION_MEASURES = "validationMeasures";

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VC_ID")
    private List<MinimalDemandBE> minimalDemands;
    public transient static final String ATTRIBUTE_MINIMAL_DEMANDS = "minimalDemands";
```

There is a precompiled query to load all hierarchy, which load some other parent objects. There is also a hint for the query - eclipselink.left-join-fetch=PP.VCBE.validationMeasures (if this is changed to eclipselink.left-join-fetch=PP.VCBE.minimalDemands, then minimal demands are loaded, but validation measures (entries with discriminator 1) are also loaded into the minimal demands collection - but those should not be loaded).

Now, when query is executed validationMeasures collection if filled with objects, but all those object are actually minimal demands and have 2 as a discriminator value in the database.

The query, which gets executed is following:

```
    SELECT * FROM V_VIEW1 t1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_VIEW0 t0 ON (t0.PP_D = t1.ID) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_VIEW2 t2 ON (t2.VC_ID = t0.ID) 
        WHERE (((t1.ID = ?) AND (t1.HP_ID = ?)) 
        AND t1.HP_IS IN (SELECT t3.ID FROM V_VIEW t3 WHERE (t3.HWPG_ID = ?)))
bind => [3 parameters bound]
```

As I can see there is no DISCRIMINATOR constraint in the query, why?

Any ideas of such a behavior? And how can I tell eclipselink to load collection, depending on discriminator value?

Comment: Can you show the query, the SQL that gets generated for it and the version?  Are you using a fetch join on any of the collections?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've edited initial question. Hope this will give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the JPQL query and hints you use to get this SQL.

So, you are saying it works when you use a join-fetch, but not a left-join-fetch?

This seems like it may be a bug, that the inheritance discriminator expression is not being included when using an outer join.  If this is the case, please log a bug for this and vote for it.

Your model is very odd though.  Why split the two subclasses into two separate relationships?  Having one would be much more efficient.  Or if you do split them, you should be using different foreign keys, not the same one.  Sharing the same foreign key for two different relationships is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Hi James! Thank you for the answer. I put it in the wrong way, sorry. I was not using join-fetch, it is still left-join-fetch but with different hint value (collection is different). I will put join-fetch just to give it a try tomorrow.

About the model: do I understand you correctly, that your suggestion is having, for instance, VC_ID in the ValidationMeasure and MD_VC_ID in MinimalDemand and then use those foreign keys in VCBE?